# Vectors in Cocoa Touch / Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, vector

Is it possible to use vectors in Coca Touch? If so, what library must be included?

I was following a general C tutorial on them an the only thing needed was to `#include <vector>`

But XCode  states that there is no such file or directory.

Any pointer to a library that provides such functionality is appreciated.

Regards
~dhp

Comment: Vectors are from C++, not C. This has a lot of implications.

Comment: `#include <vector>` is C++, not C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out... Follow the 3 steps below:

1. Extend the file name with `.mm`
2. `#include "vector"`
3. Use this code:

---

```
std::vector <<int>int> myVector(20);
instead of just using vector <<int>int> myVector(20);
```

---

Now you have a brand new C++ vector working in Objective-C.

Comment: using namespace std; would remove the need for stating the namespace before vector

Comment: Yes, but using `using namespace std;` is frequently considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 9):

Objective-C is a superset of C, and therefore anything C will work with them. However, `std::vector` is a C++ class, which means the compiler has to be aware that you're going to use C, Objective-C *and* C++ code inside your program. You can do so by changing the extension of your source files from `.m` to `.mm`.

However, if you're still at the stage of learning Objective-C or C++, try to not mix too much C++ with it. C++ uses "non-POD types" (POD being "plain old data"), which are inherently incompatible with functions that take variadic arguments; under the hood, *all* Objective-C calls work that way, so that can make it complex to work with C++ types through Objective-C calls if you're not too sure about how it all works. You could use Cocoa's `NSMutableArray` class too.

Comment: thank you for the great response. I have worked with ObjC for quite a while but have never needed to go into C++ (at all in life, and that after going through Basic / Pascal / Fortran / VB.Net / C# / ObjC and lately Java (just as I 'm getting into android)
    
But after all that I'm still scared of C++ :(
   
btw, this is the library I want to play with:    
http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Color_conversion_scripts
    
Regards and thanks again big time

Comment: @dhomes These aren't the STL vectors, but rather some third-party vector objects. The language doesn't look like C either. What they use is roughly equivalent to `struct vector { float x, y, z; };` And this is POD, so feel free to throw it in Objective-C calls.

Answer (score 4):

how about:

```
struct Vector { float r, x, y, z; };
typedef struct Vector Vector;

CG_INLINE Vector
VectorMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z)
{
    Vector vector; vector.x = x; vector.y = y; vector.z = z;return vector;
}
```

Comment: A vector in C++ std library is a type of array, not a mathematical point in space as you're thinking.